# A task about friend of friend of .... on Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables:

- Table of peoples (m_id, m_name);
- Table of links (m_id, f_id), where both fields link to m_id from first table

I need an Oracle database query  that prints the word "Possible" if everyone is linked to everyone by not more than:

1. through 3 friends
2. through N friends
3. otherwise prints "Impossible"

Help me with this task if it's possible, or at least show me where to look for the answer, I mean what I have to read before, and what's necessary for solving this task.

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: It has to be done by any version

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i got you question correct but i guess you require something like this.

```
 select p.m_id,count(l.f_id),'Possible' col
    from people p,
    links l
    where p.m_id = l.m_id
    group by p.m_id
    having count(l.f_id) >= 3
    union
    select p.m_id,count(l.f_id),'Impossible' col
    from people p,
    links l
    where p.m_id = l.m_id
    group by p.m_id
    having count(l.f_id) < 3
```

Comment: At the very least your conditions are the wrong way round: the result is 'Possible' if the number of links is `<= 3` and impossible if the number of links i sgreater than that.

Comment: Don't I have to use a recursion?